# iOS 6 sharing like Messages, not like Photos (UIActivityViewController and UIDocumentInteractionController)

Tags: ios, sharing, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument, uiactivityviewcontroller

In iOS 6, tapping the action button in the Photos app presents the standard UIActivityViewController:

[image: UIActivityViewController from Photos]

Doing the same from Messages presents a different set of options. This looks to me like it's using the UIDocumentInteractionController api to pull all the apps that say they can handle an image.

[image: UIAcitivtyViewController? from Messages]

My question is twofold:

1. How does one get into the Messages action menu? Tumblr and Halftone, to name a few, have done it... I can't seem to find the documentation.
2. How does one show the Messages-style action menu? When I present a UIActivityViewController it doesn't have those options... just the standard set facebook/twitter/copy/print/save to camera roll/etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get on that list: ["Registering the File Types Your App Supports"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)

To handle images, you probably want to register for `public.image` [(Reference)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)

To present that list, you just need to ask a [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304) to display its options menu

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear from looking at it that the former is a UIActivityViewController and the latter is a UIDocumentInteractionController. They look very similar.

Comment: @KennyWinker Not only do they look similiar, `UIDocumentInteractionController` actually uses a `UIActivityViewController` under the hood, but with some special sauce that allows it to do things that we don't have the ability to do.